# Selecting random nodes from xml file

Tags: c#, xml

My application allows the user to speak into a microphone and the program will talk back to the user. I have responses saved in a XML file and when the user talks, I want the program to check in the XML file and display a random node in the section it should. The following is what my XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<MarcusXMLFile xmlns:Responses="http://www.rewardstrike.com/XMLFile1.xml"">
  <response>
    <posanswer>
      <answer>Yes, sir.</answer>
      <answer>Right away.</answer>
    </posanswer>
  </response>
</MarcusXMLFile>
```

My code for selecting a random node is:

```
private void Responses()
{
    string query = String.Format("http://www.rewardstrike.com/XMLFile1.xml");
    XmlDocument Responses = new XmlDocument();
    Responses.Load(query);

    XmlNode channel = Responses.SelectSingleNode("MarcusXMLFile");
    XmlNodeList nodes = Responses.SelectNodes("MarcusXMLFile/response");

    try
    {
         XmlNodeList positiveresponses = Responses.SelectNodes("./posanswer/answer");
         foreach (XmlNode ans in positiveresponses.Cast<XmlNode>().OrderBy(elem => Guid.NewGuid()))
         {
             response = ans.InnerText;
         }
         QEvent = "positiveresponse";
    }
    catch { }
}
```

And my code for calling the event is:

```
case "Hello":
case "Hello Jarvis":        
     Responses();
     if (QEvent == "positiveresponse")
     {
              JMARCUS.Speak(response);
     }
     break;
```

However, when I speak to the application, it gives me an error saying the text he is supposed to speak in null. Any ideas?

Comment: Your exception handling is not optimal.. likely there is some useful exception happens but you ignore it completely.

Comment: catch {}    It's like disabling the smoke detectors in your child's bedroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `Responses.SelectNodes` finds no nodes, so `positiveresponses` has no nodes, the `foreach` loop has nothing to iterate on, and `response` is never assigned a value.

Try changing:

```
XmlNodeList positiveresponses = Responses.SelectNodes("./posanswer/answer");
```

To:

```
XmlNodeList positiveresponses
    = Responses.SelectNodes("MarcusXMLFile/response/posanswer/answer");
```

Comment: That worked. Can't believe I missed that 0_0 also, is the method I used to pick a random node a good one, or is there a better way?